# Editing JSPs that output raw JavaScript in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, jsp, intellij-idea

I'm editing JSP files that output raw JavaScript. They look something like this:

```
<%@page
    session="false"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"
    contentType="text/javascript;charset=utf-8" %>

console.log("Hello, World");
```

Unfortunately, IntelliJ IDEA 13 Ultimate is not catching up and thinks my JavaScript is horribly malformed HTML. Is there any way I can tell it to interpret the content in my JSP as JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted my prevous answer as I've realized that I had completely misunderstood your question.

I didn't manage to find a perfect solution (I'm not sure if it exists), but you may try:

- in `Settings`, go to `File Types`
- choose Javascript and click on the green plus icon next to Registered Patterns box
- type in **full name** (I mean *filename.jsp*, not **.jsp*) of your file

From now you your file will be interpreted as Javascript.

Unluckily, that means that `<%@page %>` declaration won't validate. You'll probably have to add it after you finish editing your code.